# Routing App Coverage File optional and not included, but now I can't save

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to save my app in iTunes Connect. I have done this many times before but now I am getting an error that alerts me to the Routing App Coverage File. It is saying I need to include it, but I don't and never have before. My app does not use any mapping features etc.

Is says: "Your Routing App Coverage File must be in geoJSON format". But I have no Routing file nor any need for one as my app is not using any routing capabilities

I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: The complete message would help figure that out.

Comment: Is says: "Your Routing App Coverage File must be in geoJSON format". But I have no Routing file nor any need for one as my app is not using any routing capabilities

Comment: Initially the actual message was not included inthe question.

Comment: Sure its an apple problem

Comment: Either it is now resolved, or here is how I got mine working again. I logged in and just added an extra period to the end of my Notes... Then I clicked Save. After I did that I was able to paste in my notes and Save without the Routing App Coverage alert. Although, it could just be coincidence and perhaps they fixed something behind the scenes just before I did this.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the problem on the Apple's side.
I am having the same problem right now. I've uploaded the app yesterday without any issues, and now I can't update metadata with this error.

Also a quick twitter search show that some other people have the same issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, none of my previous versions of the app included this file. Looks like a problem on Apple's side

Answer (score 1):

Was 100% on Apple's end. Oh well. They're allowed a few hic-ups ;)

All fixed now, at least for me. Hopefully for everyone else as well.